# Creating a button on View1 from View2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I'm in a struggle. I have this app with two views. View1 empty. View2 with a textfield and an OK button. I want to accomplish the following:

1. On View2 the user inserts the name for a button; its title. (the way user reaches view2 is not relevant. It could be with a button or a tabbar button on View1.)
2. After pressing OK button, View2 is removed. View1 is now visible.
3. View1, now, has on it a run-time created button with the title provided by the user.

   ---

I have tried, calling from view2 after pressing the OK button, the method on view1 that creates the button. Doesn't work. There's no error, but the button does not appear. I guess this it is not conforming to MVC, as I've been told by a forum's fellow colleague. He suggested outlets. But were? I thought of Notifications. I'm unsure it even makes any sense in this case.

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It may be overkill for this situation but one way to communicate between ViewControllers is by using the delegate pattern, [here's some info](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html) from Apple on delegates.

Comment: Hi,
after the reading, yes, delegates are probably the answer. I tried textFieldDidEndEditing delegate for a Label in View2 though, and it worked just fine. Imagine now a Label in View1. How can I use the very same textfield delegate passing View2 textfield content to a label in View1? Thanks.